# C code showing ASCII instead of character

Tags: c, ascii

I've only used C++ in the past and I was trying to convert my decimal to hex code to C. When trying to do so, I'm noticing when I try to print out a character, it prints out the ASCII value instead. I'm unsure of why it is doing this. Example: 10 in hex = A, however it prints out 65 instead. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>  

int main ()
{
    int num = 0;
    printf("Please enter an integer ");    
    scanf("%d",&num); 

    
    //shown as 8 in the example
    char hex[8];
    char hex_values[16]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    
    int count = 0;
    
    while(num > 0)
    {
        int spot = num % 16;
        hex[count] = hex_values[spot];
        num = num / 16;
        count++;
        printf("%d ", hex[count-1]);
    }
    //places zeros in front of the array... in an easy way
    int zeros = 8 - count;
    for(int q = 0; q < zeros; q++)
    {
        printf("%c", '0');
    }
    

}
```

Comment: `printf("%d ", hex[count-1]);` -> `printf("%c ", hex[count-1]);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to print with '%c' to get the ASCII representation of a number because in C char are just unsigned short int

```
printf("%c ", hex[count-1]);
```